# How do I correctly use @escaping in swift?

Tags: swift

I have been trying to deal with an @escaping closure in swift but I'm just not getting my head around it. My aim is to retrieve a download link from Google Firebase Storage  - using the id field retrieved from a DB Document (originally) so I can download via NukeUI's LazyImage but I'm clearly missing something, basically is this the best way to approach this and if so what am I doing wrong here? If there is a more suitable approach to solve this can you point me in the right direction.

the code from the swiftUI view

```
var body: some View {
  GeometryReader { geometry in
    ScrollView {
      let side = geometry.size.width / 4
      let item = GridItem(.fixed(side), spacing: 2)
 
      LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: item, count: 4), spacing: 2) {
                    
        // Image Section.
        ForEach(0..<siteData.sites.count, id: \.self) { index in
          let currentSiteURL: String = grabURL(id: siteData.sites[index].id!)
          LazyImage(source: currentSiteURL)
            .frame(width: side, height: side)
            .onAppear { model.onAppear(index) }
            .onDisappear { model.onDisappear(index) }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the function to retrieve the url to download:

```
func grabURL(id: String, completion: @escaping (String?)->Void) {
  let ref = Storage.storage().reference().child("ImagesThumb")
  ref.child("\(id).jpeg").downloadURL { (url, error) in
    if let error = error {
      print("Error Occured: \(error)")
      completion(nil)
      return
    }
    guard let siteURL = url else {
      completion(nil)
      return
    }
    completion(siteURL.absoluteString)
  }
}
```

Comment: Loading data asynchronously in the rendering area of a view is very bad practice. Don't do that. Implement an observable view model. And `(String?)->Void` as return type is dated. Use the dedicated type `(Result<String,Error>)->Void`

Comment: @vadian Well if it comes to that, both Result and completion handlers are dated.

Comment: Don't watch the Meet async await video from WWDC21

Answer (score 0):

We use `@escaping` when the `closure` passed will outlive the parent `function`. Looking at your implementation, I think it's safe to say that your use of `@escaping` is right.

However, as [vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian) commented, your data fetching function is a bad practice. Consider using `.task` and `async/await`.

Comment: thanks, i’m still learning - i’ll check that out